# Format float to currency using PySpark and Babel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, currency-formatting, python-babel

I'd like to convert a `float` to a `currency` using Babel and PySpark

sample data:

```
amount       currency
2129.9       RON
1700         EUR
1268         GBP
741.2        USD
142.08091153 EUR
4.7E7        USD
0            GBP
```

I tried:

```
df = df.withColumn(F.col('amount'), format_currency(F.col('amount'), F.col('currency'),locale='be_BE'))
```

or

```
df = df.withColumn(F.col('amount'), format_currency(F.col('amount'), 'EUR',locale='be_BE'))
```

They both give me an error:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide sample data of `amount` column and also since the error is because of the decimal conversion so you can check check if there is any `/` in the entire column of `amount`.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no other characters in the entire `amount` column apart from `numeric`?  As there is no other reason why it will have a `decimal conversion` error

Comment: I checked the table end there's an `E` in the column e.g. `4.7E7`

Comment: remove those characters and try again. Also to check whether the rows are `numeric or integer` or not, you can use `df.select("amount",F.col("amount").cast("int").isNotNull().alias("Truth")).show()`

Comment: What's the best way to remove those characters `regexp_extract` ?

Comment: yes you can use `regexp_extract` to have just the numeric part or even `regexp_replace` to remove non-numeric part with `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Python libraries with Spark dataframes, you need to use an UDF:

```
from babel.numbers import format_currency
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

format_currency_udf = F.udf(lambda a, c: format_currency(a, c))

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'amount',
    format_currency_udf('amount', 'currency')
)

df2.show()
+----------------+--------+
|          amount|currency|
+----------------+--------+
|     RON2,129.90|     RON|
|       €1,700.00|     EUR|
|       £1,268.00|     GBP|
|       US$741.20|     USD|
|         €142.08|     EUR|
|US$47,000,000.00|     USD|
+----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Works for most values but still having `InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimalConversionSyntax'>]` error. I checked all values but i can't find the cause of this. How can I best find the value causing the error?
Some values are `0` can this cause the problem ?

Comment: @JohnDoe it will fail for nulls. you can add a check in the udf to catch this.

Answer (score 1):

There seems a problem in pre-processing the `amount` column of your dataframe. From the error it is evident that `value` after converting to string is not just numeric which it has to be according to this [table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?#decimal.Decimal)and has has some additional characters as well. You can check on this column to find that and remove unnecessary character to fix this. As as example:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> value = '10.0'
>>> value = decimal.Decimal(str(value))
>>> value
Decimal('10.0')
>>> value = '10.0e'
>>> value = decimal.Decimal(str(value))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    value = decimal.Decimal(str(value))
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]   # as '10.0e' is not just numeric
```